# How to handle unicode printing require space in java

Tags: unicode, draw, space, face, card

hello there I have great problem with my methods. I wrote these methods to draw a card but in line that I have unicode for card faces it wont work correctly. because of this issue that the require space for these unicode is more than a whitespace it print it wrong. Is there anybody know how can I deal with this Issue? please help me with this issue.

First method is for card face and second is for creating multiple card together.

```
       public String[] card(){
      String[] card = new String[9];
      card[0] = ("┌───────────┐");
      card[1] = ( getNumber() < 10 ? "│ " + getNumber() +
         "         │" : "│"+( getNumber() == 10 ? "10" : getNumber() == 11 ? " J" : getNumber() == 12 ? " 
    Q" : " K")+"         │");
      card[2] = ("│           │") ;
      card[3] = ("│           │");
      card[4] = ("│─────"+ getFace() + "─────│") ;
      card[5] = ("│           │") ;
      card[6] = ("│           │") ;
      card[7] =(getNumber() < 10 ? "│         " + getNumber() +
         " │" : "│         "+( getNumber() == 10 ? "10" : getNumber() == 11 ? "J " : getNumber() == 12 ? 
    "Q " : "K ")+"│");
      card[8] = ("└───────────┘");
      return (card);
   }

   public static String renderCard(List<String[]> cards) {
      String[] lines = new String[9];
      String output = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
         for (String[] array : cards) {
            lines[i] = (lines[i]==null ? "" : lines[i]) + "   " + array[i];
         }
      }
      for(String line : lines){
         output += (line + "\n");
      }
      return output;
   }
```

Output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYxVF.png)

Comment: If you use a true-monospace font AND you have a good terminal emulator you should have the correct result. Both are know to fail often with Unicode. So check a better font and better terminal, or use other methods

Answer (score 0):

I try many ways and figure out that this problem is cause by IntelliJ IDEA pre installed font. to solve this problem must go to:
File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Font -> Font
by changing font from JetBrains Mono to Consolas this problem will be solve.